# How prove this identity$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{2k}(s-t)^{n-k}t^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2s^{n-k}t^k$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Today I see a paper,and this author say it is easy to have this identity.But I take sometimes to prove it,and I can't prove it.

> show this following identity holds for any real $s$ and $t$ and any postive integer $n$
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{2k}(s-t)^{n-k}t^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2s^{n-k}t^k$$

My some idea:
$$\binom{2k}{k}\binom{n+k}{2k}=\dfrac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\cdot\dfrac{(n+k)!}{(2k)!(n-k)!}=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\dfrac{(n+k)!}{n!k!}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}$$
so we must show this following identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}(s-t)^{n-k}t^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2s^{n-k}t^k$$
then I can't works

Comment: Why not work out $(s-t)^{n-k}$ by the binomial formula, and the compare coefficients of each monomial?

Comment: I have try it, I know you meaning $(s-t)^{n-k}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}s^i(-t)^{n-k-i}$,then it is very ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{n}\color{green}{\binom{2k}k\binom {n+k}{2k}}(s-t)^{n-k}t^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\color{green}{\binom {n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}k}\color{blue}{(s-t)^{n-k}}t^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\color{green}{\binom {n+k}{k}\binom nk} t^k\color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}rs^{n-k-r}(-t)^r}\\ 
&=\color{orange}{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}}\binom{n+k}k\binom nk\binom{n-k}rs^{n-k-r}t^{k+r}(-1)^r\\
&=\color{orange}{\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{j}}\binom{n+k}k\color{purple}{\binom nk\binom{n-k}{j-k}}s^{n-j}t^{j}(-1)^{j-k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}s^{n-j}t^j\sum_{k=0}^{j}\color{red}{\binom{n+k}k}\color{purple}{\binom n{n-k}\binom{n-k}{n-j}}(-1)^{j-k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}s^{n-j}t^j\sum_{k=0}^{j}\color{red}{\binom{-n-1}k (-1)^k}\color{purple}{\binom n{n-j}\binom{j}{k}}(-1)^{j-k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}s^{n-j}t^j\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{-n-1}k\color{purple}{\binom nj\binom j{j-k}}(-1)^{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj(-1)^{j}s^{n-j}t^j\color{darkgreen}{\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{-n-1}k\binom j{j-k}}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj(-1)^{j}s^{n-j}t^j\color{darkgreen}{\binom{-n-1+j}j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom nj(-1)^{j}s^{n-j}t^j\color{darkgreen}{\binom nj (-1)^j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\color{darkred}{\binom nj}s^{n-j}t^j\color{darkred}{\binom nj}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\color{darkred}{{\binom nj}^2} s^{n-j}t^j\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom nk}^2 s^{n-k}t^k\qquad \blacksquare 
\end{align}$$

---

*NB: The above also shows that*

$$\small\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^{j}\underbrace{\binom{n+k}k\binom nk\binom{n-k}{j-k}\color{gray}{\binom{n-j}{n-j}}}_{\Large\binom{n+k}{k,k,j-k,n-j}}(-1)^{j-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n+k}{k,k,j-k,n-j}(-1)^{j-k}\\
&={\binom nj}^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: It's very very nice! but why $$\sum_{k=0}^{j}\binom{n+k}{k,k,j-k,n-j}(-1)^{j-k}=\binom{n}{j}^2?$$

Comment: @math110 - Thank you! That's very kind of you.:) 
With regard to your question, I've edited the solution for greater clarity. Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

By  way of  enrichment here  is  another algebraic  proof using  basic
complex variables.

For the sum on the LHS which is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k} {n+k\choose 2k} (s-t)^{n-k} t^k$$
or rather
$$\sum_{k=0}^n  {n\choose k}{n+k\choose k} (s-t)^{n-k} t^k$$

introduce the integral representation
$${n+k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^{n+k}}{z^{k+1}} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$(s-t)^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
\left(\frac{1+z}{z} \frac{t}{s-t} \right)^k \; dz
\\ = (s-t)^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}
\left(1+ \frac{1+z}{z} \frac{t}{s-t}\right)^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}
\left(s-t + t \frac{1+z}{z}\right)^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}
\left(s-t + \frac{t}{z} + t\right)^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}
\left(s + \frac{t}{z}\right)^n \; dz.$$

For the sum on the RHS which is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 s^{n-k} t^k$$
introduce the integral representation
$${n\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{z^k} s^{n-k} t^k \; dz$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+z)^n}{z} \left(s+\frac{t}{z}\right)^n \; dz.$$

We have  the identical integrals for  LHS and RHS, done.   We have not
made  use  of  the  properties  of  complex  integrals  here  so  this
computation  can also be  presented using  just algebra  of generating
functions.

There is another computation in the same spirit at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064635/).

Apparently  this method is  due to  Egorychev although  some of  it is
probably folklore.

Comment: Very nice. 
If we were to approach this without using complex integrals, and note that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n+k}{2k}\binom{2k}k\color{blue}{(s-t)^{n-k}}t^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom {n+k}{k}\binom nk t^k\color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}rs^{n-k-r}(-t)^r}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk s^{n-k}t^k\color{red}{\sum_{r=0}^{n-k}\binom{n+k}k\binom{n-k}rs^{-r}(-t)^r}$$
can it be shown that the part in red reduces to $\binom nk$? If so then we have the answer, but it doesn't seem likely as it contains $s$ and $t$...

Comment: When you ask Maple it just collapses the binomial to where you started from. Owing to the dependence on $s$ and $t$ you cannot conclude that it is equal to ${n\choose k}.$ There are many choices for the red term that would give the same value of the sum.

Comment: Yes, I realise that it collapses back to the starting point. However, having isolated $\binom nk s^{n-k}t^k$ the only missing part of the product is another $\binom nk$ in order to give ${\binom nk}^2$, as in RHS, so logically one would have thought that the red part should reduce to $\binom nk$...